# Why is my JPanel not updating when I run the JPanel.setLocation(x,y) function inside of another function?

Tags: python, swing, jpanel, jython, repaint

So I've been at this for a while now. My swing skills are not bad, but right now I seem to be missing something. I've been experimenting with Jython just recently and I have been utilizing the swing package from within a Jython script.

Let me start with this: My goal is to make a JPanel slide across the JFrame. To keep it to my knowledge, I tried attempting something like this:

```
    x = 0
    while panel.getX() < frame.getWidth():
        print "panel.getX(): %i" % panel.getX()
        panel.setLocation(x,0)
        x += 5
        time.sleep(0.01)
```

But here's the gist of my confusion... I ran this in my code and it did exactly what I wanted. The JPanel slid across the JFrame and I could see it do so:

```
    from javax.swing import *
    from java.awt import *
    from java.awt.event import *
    import time

    f = JFrame()
    p = JPanel()
    p.setPreferredSize(Dimension(300,300))

    def slide():
        x = 0
        while p.getX() < f.getWidth():
            print "p.getX(): %i" % p.getX()
            p.setLocation(x,0)
            x += 5
            time.sleep(0.5)
    p.add(JLabel("hi"))
    f.getContentPane().add(p)
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
    f.setVisible(True)
    f.pack()
    slide()
```

BUT, when I add tad more complexity with events, it has no reaction at all. No updating, repainting or anything:
        from javax.swing import *
        from java.awt import *
        from java.awt.event import *
        import time

```
    f = JFrame()
    p = JPanel()
    p.setPreferredSize(Dimension(300,300))

    def slide(event):
        x = 0
        while p.getX() < f.getWidth():
            print "p.getX(): %i" % p.getX()
            p.setLocation(x,0)
            x += 5
            time.sleep(0.5)
    b = JButton(actionPerformed=slide)
    p.add(JLabel("hi"))
    f.getContentPane().setLayout(BoxLayout(f.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS))
    f.getContentPane().add(p)
    f.getContentPane().add(b)
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
    f.setVisible(True)
    f.pack()
```

Any ideas???

Thanks,
 Dave

Answer (score 0):

The loop blocks the event dispatch thread, so no events or drawing can be processed. Use a swing [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for the sliding. The documentation is for java but hopefully not too difficult to translate to python.